# How to achieve this: object->object->property

Tags: php, oop

I see a lot of code where the calls are like this.

An example:

```
$person->head->eyes->color = "brown";
$person->head->size = 10;
$person->name = "Daniel";
```

How do I achieve what I wrote above?

Comment: Try to read These articles:        
http://www.techflirt.com/tutorials/oop-in-php/php-method-chaining.html        
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: @ElzoValugi, this is not method chaining

Comment: @swidmann what would you call it?

Comment: @Daniel I would call it OOP. Method chaining is when a class method returns the class instance so you can call multiple methods on the same object... in a chain. :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thats a goood explation of method chaining :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, could not explain it better, thanks ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That just means that `$person`, `$person->head`, and `$person->eyes` each have properties that are other objects. `head` is a property of `$person`, `eyes` is a property of `$person->head`, and so on.

So, when you set `$person->head->size`, for example, you are setting the `size` property of `$person->head`, meaning `$person->head` must be an object. Put differently, the statement `$person->head->size = 10;` means `set the size property of the head property of $person to 10`.

**Example Code:**

```
<?php

class Eyes
{
    var $color = null;
}

class Head
{
    var $eyes = null;
    var $size = null;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->eyes = new Eyes();
    }
}

class Person
{
    var $head = null;
    var $name = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->head = new Head();
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->head->eyes->color = "brown";
$person->head->size = 10;
$person->name = "Daniel";

var_dump($person);
```

**This outputs:**

```
class Person#1 (2) {
  public $head =>
  class Head#2 (2) {
    public $eyes =>
    class Eyes#3 (1) {
      public $color =>
      string(5) "brown"
    }
    public $size =>
    int(10)
  }
  public $name =>
  string(6) "Daniel"
}
```

Comment: Looks really good, does this way of doing things have a name?

Comment: actually even if it looks good it can be very messy and is not recommended practice. Properties should be accessed through getter/setter methods not directly

Comment: @Daniel I don't think it has a name. It's just a feature of object-oriented programming that you can set an object's property to be another object.

Comment: @ElzoValugi That's actually the topic of some debate, but it's not really part of Daniel's question.

Comment: true, is just a comment relative to his excitement

Answer (score 0):

First thing: there are no method being called in your example.

To the answer:

This can be achieved by using another objects instances as attributes. Eg:

```
class Head{
    public $size, $eyes, $etc;
}

class Person{
    public $name, $age, $head;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->head = new Head();
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->head->size = 'XL';
```

This is one way of doing it

You can also cast arrays as objects. This will generate stdClass instances with array indexes as attributes:

```
$person = array(
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'age' => 20
);

$personObject = (object) $person;
var_dump($personObject);
```

Answer (score -3):

PHP method chaning is the secret, return on each getter method $this

```
class Person
{
    public function head()
    {
        ...
        return $this;
    }

    public function eyes()
    {
        ...
        return $this;
    }
}

$person->head->eyes->color = "brown";
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#PHP

Comment: this is not quite true. it will be $person->head()->eyes()->color;

Comment: That's not what method chaining is. `head` and `eyes` aren't methods in `$person->head->eyes->color`; they're properties.

Comment: I thought it was a general question, not especially for that code

Comment: @mischaZeng - I think the line "How do i achieve this i wrote above?" kinda sets the context to that code.